# I tried to edit Rust code in Eclipse IDE, but I got problem "Failed to create the part's controls"

Tags: eclipse, rust

I downloaded an Eclipse's extinction for Rust, but then, after creating a new Rust project, i got [this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGOMG.png)

I tried to follow some instuctions that I was able to found, including some from this website. I deleted and then downloaded Rust on my computer, I deleted and downloaded Eclipse, same with VS C++ building tools, but all this didn't help. I saw, that for some people helps to just reenter current workspace, but it was not my case. Despite this problem, default code seems to run OK, but it is almost impossible to edit. If someone had this problem or just know how to solve it, can you help please?

P.S. My English probably is not very good, so sorry for mistakes.

Comment: Click the Details button and share what it reveals.

Comment: Picture updeted. Also, at the very end of this long list it says "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.tm4e.ui.utils.ContentTypeHelper cannot be found by org.eclipse.tm4e.languageconfiguration_0.4.0.202102201711", then 5 more times "at ..." and "... 118 more"

Comment: Known issue. See https://github.com/eclipse/tm4e/issues/387#issuecomment-1120266522

Comment: The update site `https://download.eclipse.org/tm4e/snapshots` contains some kind of nightly builds which might be unstable and which requires Java 17 now. So better use [`https://download.eclipse.org/tm4e/releases/latest/`](https://download.eclipse.org/tm4e/releases/latest/).

Comment: @nitind Could you please turn your comment into an answer using the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/tm4e/releases/latest/`](https://download.eclipse.org/tm4e/releases/latest/) (which should be the same as in the 2022-06 release) instead of the snapshots update site which requires Java 17 now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. Update to the latest proper TM4E release from https://download.eclipse.org/tm4e/releases/latest/ so that you have the bundle version with this class present.